# atomicity of row locking

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, deadlock

Just got `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`.

I have a query that lock specific columns in rows and I wonder how oracle sets lock on rows matched by query? Is it atomic or not?

For example I have table with `id` and `value` columns and following query:

```
select id, value from tbl where id > 1 and id < 100 for update of value
```

There are several clients that execute this query. Is it possible to get deadlock in this case?

Comment: A bit of an aside, but you aren't locking specific columns, you're still locking the whole row. When your query is against a single table, the `of` clause doesn't do anything except indicate to you (as a comment, effectively) what you intend to do with it. If you have multiple tables than only the rows in the table which has the column you specify are locked. With one table that makes no difference - there isn't another table to leave unlocked, so it's redundant from Oracle's point of view.

Comment: @AlexPoole, thanks, good point. I thought that only one column is locked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to get deadlock in this case

It's possible, when two or more sessions are trying to acquire an exclusive lock on a resource locked by each other.

Here is a simple demonstration:

```
  create table Deadlock1(col number);

  create table DeadLock2(col number);

  insert into DeadLock1(col) values(1);
  insert into DeadLock2(col) values(1);
```

Session #1

```
  select *
    from deadlock1
   where col = 1
     for update of col
```

Session #2

```
  select *
    from deadlock2
   where col = 1
     for update of col
```

Session #1

```
  select *
    from deadlock2
   where col = 1
     for update of col
```

Session #2

```
  select *
    from deadlock1
   where col = 1
     for update of col
```

Attempt to acquire lock in session #2 if no commit or rollback has been issued in session #1, will result in `ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource`.

In your case, when session#1 is executing your query and there was no `commit` or `rollback`, session #2 will simply be blocked. There will be no deadlocking. So it must be something else that causes deadlock.

Oracle creates a trace file every time a deadlock occurs and places name and path of a newly created trace file in the alert.log file. So, you need to inspect the content of a created trace(*.trc) file to identify sessions that are blocking each other:

```
*** SESSION ID:(362.24645) 2013-09-04 14:46:05.297
*** CLIENT ID:() 2013-09-04 14:46:05.297
*** SERVICE NAME:(nkrasnov) 2013-09-04 14:46:05.297
*** MODULE NAME:(PL/SQL Developer) 2013-09-04 14:46:05.297
*** CONTAINER ID:(3) 2013-09-04 14:46:05.297

Deadlock graph:
                                          ---------Blocker(s)--------  ---------Waiter(s)---------
Resource Name                             process session holds waits  process session holds waits
TX-000B0007-00002730-00000000-00000000        138     362     X            142     441           X
TX-00050011-00000A51-00000000-00000000        142     441     X            138     362           X

session 362: DID 0001-008A-00003BE6 session 441: DID 0001-008E-0000C55F 
session 441: DID 0001-008E-0000C55F session 362: DID 0001-008A-00003BE6
```

Consider using `nowait` or starting from 11g `skip locked` option of `for update` clause.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko In that file you will find SIDs of sessions which are blocking each other(Blocker(s) and Waiter(s)). Then you write a query against `v$session` view using those SIDs and join the result with `v$sql` view using `SQL_ID` to see what statements are causing deadlock.

Comment: Could you look at my trace file, it is quite different from yours. http://pastebin.com/8F2nJPBj. I would be grateful if you explain me meaning of information after `Verified Hangs in the System`  or give link to documentation where it is described. As this deadlock happened three days ago, I can not check sessions in `v$session`.

Comment: @michaelnesterenko Seems like your trace file has been produced by Hang manager(possibly in the RAC environment) and at first glance tells you the following: Obviously there has been a hang and unresolvable one in your environment and session 771 has been verified as a victim - the cause of the hang. At this moment it's not that simply to tell what exactly had happened, but as session's 771 wait event is `SQL*Net message from client` one of the possible scenarios is: session 771 updates a row and waits for a user to commit or rollback, session 1159 and 39 hang trying to acquire row level lock.

Comment: As I understand session 771 is not blocked by anything except application? I.e. application just need to commit/rollback to release locks that other sessions need? In such case I don't understand why this is treated as deadlock?

Comment: @michaelnesterenko Basically yes. Session 771 isn't blocked it waits for application to decide what to do with the transaction.

Comment: Then how could that be a deadlock? Are there some kind of a timeout for unresponsive clients which hold locks after which such locks are considered as a deadlock?